# Image map on a keyframe div

Tags: html, css, dictionary, imagemap

I have an image map with several coordinates. However, this one is not working when I put a keyframe div (`clouds`) above since the animation is covering the map. This last div is an animation with some clouds passing over the image.

The html code is:

```css
    .column-right img {
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .column-right .clouds {
      animation: cloud-move 25s linear 2s infinite;
      background-image: url("../img/sobre_mi/clouds.png");
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 5;
    }
    map {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 50;
    }
```

```html
<img src="img/sobre_mi/map.jpg" alt="Map" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map">
  <area shape="circle" coords="970,247,90" href="#" alt="Córdoba">
</map>
<div class="clouds"></div>
```

My question is, is there any way to achieve that an image map works while an animation is developping over it?

I have done some testings like playing with the z-index on the map and area tags in order to be in front of div `clouds` but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Could you place an image of the 'map' on z-index 0, then place the clouds on top, then position absolute a transparent gif/png image on top of that which has the image map coordinates that call the . So the animation is below but still visible. Just an idea...